# How to upload app to the App Store with OneSignal plugin? ERROR ITMS-90362 "MinimumOSVersion" invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, onesignal

I am having some issues related to the OneSignal plugin on IOS. In Xcode after archiving the app, when I try to upload the app to the AppStore I get this error:

> **iTunes Store Operation Failed**
>
> ERROR ITMS-90362: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key
> 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle
> fsa.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is
> invalid. This extension requires a version of iOS higher than the
> value specified for the MinimumOSVersion key in Info.plist."

I've tried to change the value manually in the Info.plist file related to the OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension, but I still got this error. In Unity I've set the minimum iOS version to 9.0. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Additional information, I've used these tutorial to setup the project:

[Unity SDK Setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/unity-sdk-setup)

[Generate an iOS Push Certificate](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate)

**Version:**

Xcode 9.0

Unity 5.6.1f1

OneSignal 2.4.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the Deployment Target so it is grayed out in the Notification Service Extension Deployment Target field as so:

[image]

Comment: Ok, it is grayed out as version 11.0, but when I try to archive I receive the error: 

**Invalid iOS deployment version '-miphoneos-version-min=11.0', iOS 10 is the maximum deployment target for 32-bit targets**

Comment: I don't know exactly how I solved but, in xcode, there is a resolver for this problem, it runs automatically. After that it worked! Thanks!